# Installing gensim in windows 7

Tags: python, gensim

I am trying to install gensim python library. However I am facing some dependencies errors. I ve isntalled schipy and numpy throught canopy. Next step to use pip install gensim in order to get gensim package. However I am getting error messages. I have installed python 2.7.4. I ve got visual studio 2010 installed on my machine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you posting errors as screenshots instead of text?

Comment: Yea not so elegant, but it was rather difficult to write it to text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some minutes googling, thanksfully I think I found a solution. Basically I read this post in :[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat). What I did is to re-install scipy. Afterthat I install libpython from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).